# Force z-index of series in Kendo UI chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I need to draw a Kendo UI chart with 2 series of different types: `candlestick` and `line`: http://jsfiddle.net/BDAvq/

I want the `candlestick` series to be drawn behind the `line` one, but whatever the order of my `series` array the `candlestick` series is always drawn on top.

Is there any way I can force the relative depth of these 2 series ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by setting the opacity as follows:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [
      {
          type: 'candlestick',
          data: [
              { low: 1, high: 5.01, open: 1, close: 5 },
              { low: 4, high: 5, open: 4.01, close: 5 },
          ], 
          opacity: 0.5
      },
      {
          type: 'line',
          data: [ 3, 6 ]
      },
  ]
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5krac/1/